# how to delete a line(record) from a file using php

Tags: php, file, sed, awk, file-processing

I want to delete a line which has unique id at the end of the line. how to delete the line? Is there any implementation of sed or awk in php? my file structure is as follows

> ```
> 1 0 * * *  echo -n "cron 1" > /www/apache/logs/error_log #1
> 0 */2 * * *  /home/user/test1.pl #2
> 1 0 * * *  echo -n "cron 2" > /www/apache/logs/error_log #3
> 0 */2 * * *  /home/user/test2.pl #4
> 1 0 * * *  echo -n "cron 3" > /www/apache/logs/error_log #5
> 0 */2 * * *  /home/user/test3.pl #6
> ```

in the above example unique id is at the end of each line with "#" followed by the integer id value. How to delete a line by identifying with its unique key? Thanks.

Comment: surprise! php can run external programs using `system()` function

Comment: tagged your question with sed, & awk is already a **BIG minus** for cross platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with awk, (eg deleting #4 line )

```
awk -v uniq="#4" '$NF!~uniq' file > temp && mv temp file
```

in PHP, you can iterate the file and look for the id with regex : `"#\d+$"`, or you can split the line on whitespace and check that the last element is not the uniq number you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Smth like

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(preg_match("/#(\d+)/$"), $line, $matches) && ($matches[1]==$drop_line_num)){
        #DON'T write line in output file
    }else{
        #write line to output file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`:

`grep -v '#3$' filename`

With `sed`:

`sed -e '/#3$/d' filename`

to remove only the line with a `#3` at its end.

Answer (score 1):

Bare PHP will do.

```
function removeTaggedLine ($tag, $file_name)
{
    $lines = preg_grep ("/#$tag$/", file ($file_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
    file_put_contents ($file_name, join ("\n", $lines) . "\n");
}

removeTaggedLine ('3', 'name of the file');
```